# How to query for this specific result?

Tags: sql

Table E :

- Unique ID `Entry_Number`.
- Group key `Group` (to associate records together, not unique, corresponds to foreign table G where it is unique key).
- Status `Entry_Status` (character indicators of a real-life process: A, R, C, I).

Table G :

- Unique ID `Group_Number` (corresponding to group key).
- Group status `Group_Status` (true or false).

I want to query for entry numbers from table E where `Entry_Status` = A or R, and if entries with same `Group_Number` also have `Entry_Status` = A or R (the part I can't figure out) and if `Group_status` for that `Group_Number` = false (ignore entries with `Group_Number` associated with TRUE `Group_Status` regardless of `Entry_Status`). Example:

Table E:

| Entry_Number | Group | Entry_Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 1 | A |
| 13 | 1 | A |
| 14 | 1 | R |
| 15 | 2 | A |
| 16 | 2 | I |
| 17 | 3 | A |
| 18 | 3 | C |

Table G:

| Group_Number | Group_Status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | False |
| 2 | False |
| 3 | True |

I should get [12,13,14]. Group 2 is rejected since status of entry 17 = I and Group 3 is rejected because `Group_Status` = True.

```
SELECT ENTRY_NUMBERS
FROM ENTRY E, GROUP G
WHERE G.GROUP_STATUS = 'FALSE'
AND E.STATUS IN ('A','R')
```

This does not take entries with same `Group_Number` into account. How do I relate entries within same table according to `Group_Number`, then checking status of those other entries to decide if the original should be considered?

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask about 1 bad definition/query/function with the obligatory [mre] & why you think it should return something else at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do & ideally a [mre]. But please ask about the former 1st because misconceptions in the former will get in the way of understanding the latter. And bad code doesn't tell us what you wish it would do. [ask] [Help] MySQL<>Oracle. Which?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

Sample data:

```
SQL> with
  2  entry (entry_number, group_number, status) as
  3    (select 12, 1, 'A' from dual union all
  4     select 13, 1, 'A' from dual union all
  5     select 14, 1, 'R' from dual union all
  6     select 15, 2, 'A' from dual union all
  7     select 16, 2, 'I' from dual union all
  8     select 17, 3, 'A' from dual union all
  9     select 18, 3, 'C' from dual
 10    ),
 11  t_group (group_number, status) as
 12    (select 1, 'False' from dual union all
 13     select 2, 'False' from dual union all
 14     select 3, 'True'  from dual
 15    )
```

Query begins here:

```
 16  select e.entry_number
 17  from entry e
 18  where e.status in ('A', 'R')
 19    and not exists (select null
 20                    from t_group g
 21                    where g.group_number = e.group_number
 22                      and g.status = 'True'
 23                   )
 24    and not exists (select null
 25                    from entry e1
 26                    where e1.group_number = e.group_number
 27                      and e1.status not in ('A', 'R')
 28                   )
 29  order by e.entry_number;

ENTRY_NUMBER
------------
          12
          13
          14

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions and a conditional expression to check the status of other entries of the same group, and join the other table to filter on the group status:

```
select e.entry, e.numbers
from (
    select e.*, 
        min(case when group_status in ('A', 'R') then 1 else 0 end) 
            over(partition by group_number) as keep_row
    from t_entry e
) e
inner join t_group g on g.group_number = e.group_number
where e.keep_row = 1 and g.group_status = 'FALSE'
```